# Angular 6 Service work ,Not Loaded Inside spring war

Tags: spring-boot, angular6, angular-service-worker

I Have Spring Boot Project , have rest API and WebService , the front end is angular 6, i tested the Service work to cache the front end files for the prod mode. [service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) . When i make build prod for the front end and test with npm http-server,the service worker work fine. But when i Package the angular front end files with the Spring War the service worker never be loaded. some tracking i add below to main.ts and the result is : Service Worker **Not** Loaded (if i run from the deployed spring boot war). Also i disabled the spring security and didn't be loaded also. Any Idea Please ?

```
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(baseUrl);
    console.log('Service Worker Loaded');

  } else {
    console.log('Service Worker **Not** Loaded');
    console.log(navigator);
  }
```

Comment: i found service worker wasn't loaded becuase i was test on http not https, and to test on http service you may use  "google-chrome --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://IP:Port/Context/"". but still didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can use `http-server -c-1 dist/` to run the app after taking a production build.

Comment: yes this is work fine with me, but when i package it inside war and deploy on WildFly it not works

Comment: Can you post your spring boot config